# Minha subquery esta sobrescrevendo uma coluna da tabela buscada

Tags: mysql

Estou montando uma listagem de posts, onde alem das informações do post eu preciso das informações da casa que fez o post.

Fiz o seguinte query das tabelas `posts` e `casas`:

```
SELECT * FROM posts, (SELECT * FROM casas) AS sqlcasas 
WHERE casa = $c_id AND casa = sqlcasas.id
```

mas essa query está sobrescrevendo a coluna `id` da tabela `posts` pelo `id` da `casa`. Por exemplo:

```
[
    {
        "id": "9",
        "casa": "9",
        "midia": "/1564714715.png",
        "texto": "...",
        "data": "...",
        "likes": "26",
        "nome": "...",
        "endereco": "...",
        "cidade": "...",
        "telefone": "...",
        "logo": "/1564714696.png",
        "site": "...",
        "facebook": "...",
        "instagram": "..."
    }
]
```

E no meu front-end esse endpoint precisa me retornar tanto o id da casa quanto o id do post.

Minhas tabelas:

```
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `casas`;

CREATE TABLE `casas` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nome` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `endereco` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `cidade` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `telefone` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `logo` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `site` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `facebook` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `instagram` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;



# Dump da tabela posts
# ------------------------------------------------------------

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `posts`;

CREATE TABLE `posts` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `casa` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `midia` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `texto` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `data` date NOT NULL,
  `likes` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `casa` (`casa`),
  CONSTRAINT `post_casa` FOREIGN KEY (`casa`) REFERENCES `casas` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Tentei essa query, mas retornou um erro no meu `mysqli_query()`.

```
SELECT id AS id_post, casa FROM posts (SELECT id AS id_casa FROM casas) WHERE casa = id_casa
```

Comment: A primeira coisa é tirar esses asteriscos aí, e  usar o nome dos campos, e depois por aliases para diferenciar. Exemplo: SELECT `id AS id_post, texto, campo... FROM posts (SELECT id AS id_casa, endereco, cidade) WHERE ...` assim você terá os IDs separadamente como `id_post` e `id_casa`. Além disso, só trará os campos realmente necessários e se um dia acrescentar ou tirar um campo da tabela, a manutenção fica  bem mais fácil.

Comment: Fiz isso e me retornou o seguinte erro: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, bool given in [...]

Comment: Eu ate tinha visto realmente essa pergunta que você marcou como duplicada mas como a solução dela não resolveu pra mim eu abri essa.

Comment: Infelizmente, se não resolveu foi falta de aplicar adequadamente, pois o caminho regular é usar o Alias mesmo. Sobre o erro de `mysqli_fetch_assoc();` é erro de sintaxe no uso da funçao, nada relacionado ao SQL. De qq forma, pode deixar comentário com mais detalhes.

Comment: Então, foi por isso mesmo que eu abri uma nova pergunta porque aquela não era a mesma que a minha, mesmo sendo sobre o mesmo assunto. E a resposta do Murilo já me ajudou e eu já marquei ela como a solução da minha pergunta! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boa noite.
Bom, pelo que entendi você tem a tabela casa e a tabela post, e pelo visto o relacionamento das tabelas seria que 1 casa pode fazer N posts correto?
Então acredito que na modelagem do seu banco você deve ter criado a tabela post contendo uma chave estrangeira (que seria o id da tabela casa).
Algo assim:

TabelaCasa

id_casa
rua
numero
cidade

TabelaPost
id_post
id_casa
textPost
dataHoraPost

Se for isso você pode utilizar o join no select:

```
SELECT a.id_casa,a.rua,a.numero,a.cidade,b.textPost,b.dataHoraPost FROM TabelaCasa as a
       INNER JOIN TabelaPost as b ON a.id_casa = b.id_casa
```

Desse modo ele vai trazer todas as informações das casas que tiverem post junto com as informações do post.

Espero ter ajudado.

[Edit]
Agora que incluiu o schema das tabelas consegui ver o problema da query.
A sua FOREIGN KEY da tabela POSTS chama "casa", então você deve utilizar a seguinte query:

```
$query = "SELECT c.*, p.* FROM casas AS c INNER JOIN posts as p ON c.id = p.casa WHERE c.id = $c_id";
```

Comment: Sim, ela tem a FK. Mudei sua query para a minha trocando apenas os nomes das tabelas e colunas e não retornou nenhum post. Eis minha query: SELECT c.* FROM casas AS c
              INNER JOIN posts as p ON c.id = p.id

Comment: Aa é porque você se esqueceu de colocar os dados do post, você só especificou c.* coloca assim:
SELECT c.*,p.* FROM casas AS c INNER JOIN posts as p ON c.id = p.id

Comment: Retornou vazio novamente.

Comment: Coloca aqui no comentário a sua query para eu ver com esta montando ela por favor

Comment: $query = "SELECT c.*, p.* FROM casas AS c INNER JOIN posts AS p ON c.id = p.id";

Comment: A query esta correta, ela deve te retornar todas as casas e com o ID das casas ela procura na tabela POSTS se tem algum ID igual ao da CASA, como não esta retornando nenhum post não deve ter IDs iguais nas duas tabelas. Você poderia editar a sua pergunta colocando o schema das suas tabelas?

Comment: Editei e coloquei o SQL das minhas tabelas

Comment: Editei minha resposta incluindo o sql que provavelmente vai funcionar pra você

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97175/discussion-between-luan-davi-and-murilo-portugal).